# Select json data from mysqli and sum it for prometheush

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have taken over the work on a certain service after a certain person. My current task is to capture data from MySQLi and throw it into metrics for prometheus. I was able to do this from one table, unfortunately the other table has data in json which is in the 'data' column.
Example:

```
{
    'lang': "en",
    'space': {
        "hasOffice": "0",
        "surfaceType": 1,
        "officeAddress": "",
        "officeLocation": null
    },
    "terms": {
        "space": "economical",
        "office": 7,
        "rentTime": "3",
        "openspace": 40
    }
}
```

I have about 200 of these rows - and the number will increase. Is there any easy way to retrieve this data actively? For example, I would need to sum up how many rows of data have lang: en.

Comment: Yes, a number of ways. Do you want to do it in PHP or in a Query? It would be useful to know which version of MySQL/mariaDB you are using as later versions have more JSON oriented SQL available than earlier version

Comment: Previously, I used query for regular data, but I want the most optimal solution. I cant check mysql version from console becouse i dont have permission and server admin sleep, but phpmyadmin says 5.7.36-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 - (Ubuntu)

Comment: So thats MySQL5.7.36

Comment: So I suggest you read this section [in the MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html) To get you started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have JSON data in DB? And you wont to query/search this data. And you have MySQL 5.7 (which supports JSONS)..

So what you could do is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM some_table WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(<json_column>,'$.lang') = 'en'
```

And this would return you back number of rows with en language set.

There are multiple ways of working with JSONs, please read more here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html.

For example, you could do something like this in JSON:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(<json_column>,'$.space.surfaceType') <> 1
```

And this would return back ALL records where surfaceType is not 1...There are several other options with JSONs.